# How do I run ngRepeat on obj with strings

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

Im trying to run `ng-repeat` on this obj to display `"settings"`:

```
var settingsTest = {
            "id": "2",
            "active": "1",
            "settings": {
                "action":0,
                "somestaff":0,
                "message":0,
                "mouth":0,
                "heost":0,
                "gaming":0,
                "live.live":0,
                "notifications": 0,
                "profile": 0
            }
        };
```

And here is HTML to display it:

```
<ul>
   <li ng-repeat="(name, value) in settingsTest['settings'] | orderBy: 'name'">
   </li>
</ul>
```

At the end it gives me an error that the message has to be a string.

Comment: I tryed it, didnt work, possibly I did it wrong

Comment: what is your controller code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, make sure your `settingsTest` is on the `$scope` or controller -- as you have it, `var settingsTest = [...]`, the view is not going to know about it.

```
$scope.settingsTest = {
   ...
}
```

Then, in your view:

```
<li ng-repeat="(setting, value) in settingsTest.settings">
  {{setting}} {{value}}
</li>
```

See [jsBin](http://jsbin.com/taqilolelu/1/edit?html,js,output)

Comment: don't you need (settings, value)?

Comment: No, those are just just aliases.  You could have `(whatever, youWant)` as long as you call them correctly in the `{{whatever}} {{youWant}}` markup @JoshStevens

Comment: ohh cool! yeah makes sense, i just like them to match! :) OCD

Comment: that solved the issue , exessively silly mistake... thanks everyone!!!

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
<li ng-repeat="(settings, value) in settingsTest.settings">{{settings}} {{value}}</li>
```